# Blazor .NET 8 RC 1 How to self publish via VS Code or Visual Studio 2022 Community?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, release-candidate

How can I publish my .NET 8 RC 1 blazor app to Azure Web App Service?

with Visual Studio it says current version does not support targetting .net 8.0?

[image]

And with VS Code, I can publish but then see this error message?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the available container image that was found is for a preview release of .net 8. Is it possible to update the update the container image in Docker to the new .net 8 rc candidate? It looks like a new image is [available](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) here.

Comment: Hi  I need some help on how to do this, I currently - within vs code - right click the relevant app service and deploy to web app ... option

How do I specifiy a specific docker container?

Comment: Is this a standard Azure App Service or is it a containerized App? If it is the standard Azure App Service it doesn't look like they have updated the framework for .Net 8 to the rc1 version yet. See instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-linux) on how to check.

Comment: ok, i will await MS to update their standard Azure app service for .net 8, I am not yet familiar with how to push a custom docker container to an Azure app service that contains .NET 8.0 RC1 myself.